# how do i use the data once i decode the url?

Tags: javascript, html, url

test1.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function tally()
{
    var scrt_var = 10;


    var Dpoint, Ipoint, Hpoint, Apoint;
    var party_Score = ['Dpoint', 'Ipoint', 'Hpoint', 'Apoint'];
    var D, I, H, A;
    var value_Point;
    var type_Choice;
    var tag_Choice;


    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        iLength = inputs.length,
    D = I = H = A = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++) if (inputs[i].checked)
    {
        value_Point = parseInt(inputs[i].value);
        if (inputs[i].name.search('D') > -1){ D += value_Point; }
        if (inputs[i].name.search('I') > -1){ I += value_Point; }
        if (inputs[i].name.search('H') > -1){ H += value_Point; }
        if (inputs[i].name.search('A') > -1){ A += value_Point; }
    }
Dpoint = D;
Ipoint = I;
Hpoint = H;
Apoint = A;

location.href = "test3.html?D="+ Dpoint + "&I=" + Ipoint + "&H=" + Hpoint + "&A=" + Apoint;


}
// ]]>
</script>
</head> 

<form method="Get" action="test3.html">
<table>
<tr>
<td>question1</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="1"> 1 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="2"> 2 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="3"> 3 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="4"> 4 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="5"> 5 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="6"> 6 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="7"> 7 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="8"> 8 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="9"> 9 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="10"> 10 </td>              
</tr>
<tr>
<td>question2</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>question3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
                <td><label> question4 </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A1" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 14 -->
            <tr>
                <td><label> question5 </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
            <tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<a href="javascript:tally()"> press here</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

test3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getParams(){
var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
var params = new Array();
if (idx != -1) {
var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
}
}
return params;
}
params = getParams();

D = unescape(params["D"]);
I = unescape(params["I"]);
H = unescape(params["H"]);
A = unescape(params["A"]);

//check here
    alert(D);// the data is passed here i am sure

document.getElementById('Dtag').style.width = D + 'px';
document.getElementById('Itag').style.width = I + 'px';
document.getElementById('Htag').style.width = H + 'px';
document.getElementById('Atag').style.width = A + 'px';

// i cant use the D here to change my style and width , i have the D data but i cant use it

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: .8em Calibri, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
br {
    clear: left;
}
.bar {
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#Dtag, #Itag, #Htag, #Atag{
    background-color: #039;
    height: 16px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="results">
    <h2>Your result: <span id="type"></span></h2>
    <p><big>“ <em id="tagline"></em> ”</big></p>
    <label><strong>fish</strong></label><div class="bar"><div id="Dtag"></div></div><br>
    <label><strong>dog</strong></label><div class="bar"><div id="Itag"></div></div><br>
    <label><strong>cat</strong></label><div class="bar"><div id="Htag"></div></div><br>
    <label><strong>Bug</strong></label><div class="bar"><div id="Atag"></div></div><br>

</body>


</html>
```

i have successful bypass the radio data to next page , but somehow i cant use it to changed my style and use the data i have on java script , what did i done wrong ? you can try copy and past those code.

Comment: It looks like you should start learning a serverside language instead, you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to do, but if you need to have the data from one page in another. You could have a look at localstorage or sessionstorage. If that's not working you really should use a server side script. Please explain what you want to do with your code.

Comment: my intention is to make a question page score by radio , then creating a graph point depends on the user score , i have being looking all over the internet , this is the only way i found it easy,can any one of you show me a way ? i looked sessionstorage too but they say some browers will fail if they dont have support it.so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's not the best way to pass data from one page to another, but you can make this work. In fact, your mistake is that you query document elements before they are created. To overcome this you can move your script to the bottom of the page or wrap it into somthing like

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    .......
  });
```

Comment: my intention is have all the radio total point and passing to next page creating a graph for the radio score by the user.

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {   document.getElementById('Dtag').style.width = D + 'px';
document.getElementById('Itag').style.width = I + 'px';
document.getElementById('Htag').style.width = H + 'px';
document.getElementById('Atag').style.width = A + 'px';            }); so do i add like this ?

Comment: thank i have it work , by the way what is the best way to pass this data to other side ? please show me a way to do it. thank appreciate your help.

Comment: It is purely my opinion and of course it depends on the project, but I would say that if you want to pass data from one page to another - consider some server-side programming, and if you want to do everything with JavaScript - consider making it a "one-page" application